# problem with jackson-core when building with gradle

Tags: gradle, jackson, gradlew

When i try to build my project with gradle (clean, or check) i have the error below:

[image]

the commands that i used are

```
./gradlew clean or ./gradlew check
```

The version of gradle that i use is 7.5.1.
I have this error in my local repository and in github action also.
How can i resolve this issue?

Thank's!